# Explain what respond_to? :should in cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I am using ruby on rails and cucumber for the first time.  I am trying to define step definitions and was hope someone could explain the following code that i found in the steps definitions for me:

```
Then /^(?:|I )should see movies: "([^\"]*)"/ do |movie_list| #handles a text containing a text list of movies to check for
    if page.respond_to? :should
        page.should have_content(movie) #checks if movie appears on page
    else
    assert page.has_content?(text)
    end
end
```

My scenario is:

```
Scenario: all ratings selected
Given I am on the RottenPotatoes home page
Then I should see all movies
```

and 
I am trying to test if all items from the database are being displayed.  I am supposed to use the `.should` and `assert` on the rows of a database.  The hint I got was to `assert` that `rows.should == value`, but can't get it to work because I don't even understand it!

So upon further understanding, I produced the follow method to handle the above scenario:

```
Then /^I should see all movies$/ do
  count = Movie.count
  assert rows.should == count unless !(rows.respond_to? :should)
end
```

but cucumber is still failing that scenario.  suggestion?

Comment: I think you need to provide a bit more context to your question.  Where is this code?  What is the sequence it is part of?

Comment: can you share your `.feature` file and the step_definitions file?

Comment: the whole thing?  Is there a way to share files, or is it copy/paste?

Comment: copy paste the bits your want looked at or use a gist https://gist.github.com/

Comment: there's nothing else to put up.  I'm trying to implement the scenario provided.  But I have no idea how because I don't understand the bit I need to use.  So I just want to understand the bits.  Since the hint said to use assert and .should, that's what I want to understand.  I know what assert does.  I don't understand the other parts that I found in the example so I'm hoping that by having someone explain them, I can figure out what I need to implement the scenario.  Is there something more I should add?

Answer (score 4):

Here's an explanation, line by line:

```
Then /^(?:|I )should see movies: "([^\"]*)"/ do |movie_list| #handles a text containing a text list of movies to check for
  # Does page respond to the should method? If it does, RSpec is loaded, and
  # we can use the methods from it (especially the should method, but
  # sometimes others)
  if page.respond_to? :should
    # Does the page contain the string that the movie variable refers to?
    # I'm not sure where this variable is being defined - perhaps you mean
    # movie_list?
    page.should have_content(movie) #checks if movie appears on page
  else
    # RSpec is not installed, so let's use TestUnit syntax instead, checking
    # the same thing - but it's checking against the variable 'text' - movie_list
    # again? Or something else?
    assert page.has_content?(text)
  end
end
```

With all that in mind - when you're writing your own steps, just use the RSpec approach (if you're using RSpec) *or* the TestUnit approach. You don't need `if page.respond_to? :should` everywhere in your step definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in your steps, your Given should tell capybara to visit the correct page

Such as

```
Given ....
  visit '/url for movies'
```

This will visit the url and load the page into the page variable

```
Then /^(?:|I )should see movies: "([^\"]*)"/ do |movie_list| #handles a text containing a text list of movies to check for
    page.should have_content 'something that you are looking for'
end
```

If you are working with a blank database, i.e. no movies in it, you will need to define a movie in the Given block.

There is a very good introduction here http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec-cucumber